# How to add background image data in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to fill image data with white background. How can I add white background data with image data.

I'm using the following scenario:-

```
var imageData = shapesContext.getImageData(x,y,width,height);

context.putImageData(imageData,x,y);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using only a single color, what about using fillRect instead?

```
context.fillStyle="white";
context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

~Cheers

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391149/how-to-scale-imagedata-using-html5/11391504#11391504) question for more details.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

var c2=document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx2=c2.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeRect(5,5,25,15);

ctx2.drawImage(c, 10, 10);
```